# Big O notation of $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\ \frac{n}{2} \end{array} \right)$

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

What is the O-notation  (or $\Theta$ notation ) of $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\ \frac{n}{2} \end{array} \right)$ ?
Can I use Sterling approximation : $n! = \Theta(\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n)$ and evaluate my function as $\Theta\left(\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Just be careful to do the "arithmetics" correctly. I'd recommend to 1) apply the definition of the binomial, then use the $\sim$-asymptotic for factorials, and 3) use $\lim f/g$ with some lemmas to prove your claim. Our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth) has some material.

Comment: I'm just a bit unsure of how much carefulesness I need to apply.  
will this calculation suffice?   
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n}{2}!}{ {\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^{n/2}}} \in (0, \infty)$$

Comment: That's not a calculation. If you can edit the question to add your whole attempt, people can have a look.

Comment: Regarding carefulness, something that doesn't work is to set up $\lim f/g$, then replace $f$ and $g$ with $\Theta$-asymptotics and start doing arithmetics; you're working towards a constant, but Landau notation hides those. Using $\sim$-asymptotics, on the other hand, just works (maybe citing a suitable lemma).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.